# Multimodule project: gradle doesn't find submodules

Tags: gradle, build, module, libgdx

I am trying to make a project with a Spring server and LibGDX client using IntelliJ.
I imported the client as a module, set the config files, and got the error:
Project with path ':core' could not be found in project ':SnakeClient'
Module path:
root
|-client
|-android
|-core
|-html
|-desktop

All of these are modules.
How could I make Gradle to find this module?

```
`settings.gradle (in module SnakeClient)
    include 'core', 'desktop', 'android', 'html'`
```

```
``build.gradle (in module SnakeClient)
    ...
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
        implementation project(':desktop')
        implementation project(':html')
        implementation project(':android')
    }
    allprojects {...`
`
```

I tried to take out settings.gradle, because somewhere I read only 1 is needed per project, but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your `settings.gradle` should look like this:

```
include 'core'
include 'desktop'
include 'android'
include 'html'`
```